# Automatically clean the project on Run in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on a `CocoaPods` iOS framework that will be later published and used via `CocoaPods`. I am in the middle of development. I have an Example project within, that points back to my framework via static path in the `Podfile` and which facilitates in the development.

Now every time I fix/change something in my framework, I need to clean the project and run `Xcode` to see my changes. Otherwise, changes don't take affect.

I am looking a way to automatically clean my project when I hit Run on Xcode.

My `Xcode` version is 11.1.

Answer (score 1):

Add a run script in your build phases and do
`xcodebuild  -sdk "${TARGET_SDK}" -xcconfig "${CONFIG_FILE_PATH}"  -configuration Debug clean`

A simple `xcodebuild clean` should do as well depending on your needs look at the [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014588-CH1-HOW_DO_I_BUILD_MY_PROJECTS_FROM_THE_COMMAND_LINE_)

Comment: A little bit of details would help along. What have you done and what was the problem? It worked here for me.

Comment: Do you actually want to rebuild your CocoaPods or clean your Xcode project?

Comment: When I press Cmd+Opt+K, Xcode cleans my project along with the CocoaPods targets as well. So that when I run, the project, CocoaPods framework is rebuilt. I want that thing to be achieved via Xcode run script.

Comment: Though I am able to achieve it via my custom script but in that case, I have to use my own custom script to run the app. Not the Xcode's run button.

Comment: You can run your project via xcode run button and your custom script will run as well. maybe you should add `pod install` after your clean your project

Comment: You are right, I need `pod install`. But when I press cmd+opt+k to clean the project, pod libraries are built and I don't need to run `pod install` in that case. So I was looking a script base alternative for cmd+opt+k command.